# OpenGL: SSBO vs "Buffer Texture" vs "PBO / Texture" to feed compute shader

Tags: opengl

I need to feed float data to a compute shader.

The 3 ways I see of doing that are:

- Shader Storage Buffer Objects
- Buffer Texture
- 'classic' Texture (upload data to GPU using a PBO, then copy data to texture using glTexSubImage2D) and accessed as 'image2D' in the shader

What are the pros / cons / performance of each technique ?

I don't need filtering, I just need to access the raw float data. Since SSBO and Buffer Texture are 1D, that means if my data is '2D', I need to compute the offsets myself.

Comment: "*access the raw float data*" OK, so... what *is* the "raw float data"? Is it multidimensional? How big is it? What does it represent?

Comment: They're complex floats (real and imaginary parts) that represent a time series. It's a continuous flow of millions of points per seconds, that I send on process on the GPU per "batch" (probably up to 1M points in a batch). So not multi dimensional originally, but the first operation on them is a FFT by block of 1024 so that kind of makes them into an array of 1024 * N ...

Answer (score 1):

- Buffer Texture - useless
- Texture - if your data is matrix-type and can fit 4 channel-float it could be little faster than pure buffer, you can utilize functions like textureGather and texture filtering
- Image - like texture, but no samplers
- SSBO - universal solution, same performance as image, you can still put 2D array in buffer and index as `data[y][x]`